# How to filter rows based on columns with maximum value?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table as below

```
--------Table 1----------
ID     VERSION     STATUS
001       1          1
001       1          2
002       1          3
002       2          4
002       2          3
```

So here I need to filter the ID's based on the max value of version and status. The expected result is below

```
--------Table 1----------
ID     VERSION     STATUS
001       1          2
002       2          4
```

I tried using the code

```
select * 
from "table1" 
where "VERSION" = (select max("VERSION") from  "table1") 
  and "STATUS" = (select max("STATUS") from "table1")
```

But it is not working. Please help

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Do you have a unique id on each row?

Comment: What in cases of "ties" where the status MAX() value is the same in the ID, VERSION group?  Do you need both records or just a single..

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, a simple group by with `max` should do it:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(VERSION) As Version, MAX(STATUS) As Status
FROM table1
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: indeed i also was wondering about the window function answers, Topicstarter you would most like have to add a `ORDER BY ID` as MySQL 8 does not sort GROUP BY annymore..

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,max(version),max(status) from 
table1
group by id
```

Comment: Topicstarter you would most like have to add a `ORDER BY ID` as MySQL 8 does not sort GROUP BY annymore..

Answer (score 0):

most dbms support row_number(), you can try like below

```
   select * from 
    (select *,row_number() over(partition by id order by status desc) rn
    from table_name
    ) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by version desc, status desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id,version,status from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by status desc) rn from YOURTABLE
) t
where rn=1
```

Comment: the SQL tag is about writing ANSI/ISO SQL standard code not about SQL Server (MSSQL)